# How do you pronounce the name "Liqun"

Tags: names

The title already describes what i would like to know.

How to pronounce the Chinese name Liqun.

Comment: Is Liqun their given name? Or is "Li" the surname and "Qun" the given name, as Tang Ho assumes? Either way, if you want to know how it's _pronounced_, I would look at [this chart](https://www.yoyochinese.com/chinese-learning-tools/Mandarin-Chinese-pronunciation-lesson/pinyin-chart-table) which has audio recordings of all Mandarin syllables (e.g., li and qun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“李群” “/Lǐ Qún/ I think

李 /li3/ is a common family name

/qun2/ can be 裙(skirt), 羣 or 群 (multitude;crowd; group)

*I don't think any parent would name their child 李裙*

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: 琼 is a common character that is also pronounced qun in some dialects.